# Alternative to cron jobs for browser type game

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have some question concerning databases and cron jobs for repeated actions. My objective is to update some values in the database every 5 minutes. The idea is to have a classic ressource system that increases over time even when users are offline. I can't figure out the best or safest way to achieve this in terms of performance. It looks like there are 3 different ways to make this :

- 1st/ Create a cron job to launch a script every hour. Since I can't have cron every 5 minutes with my hosting package, I figured I would have a loop inside the file that would repeat the action 12 times with in each loop a sleep(300) taking a total amount of one hour. Basically when this one finishes, the cron launches another one for another hour. This method would be quite expensive since the server would pretty much run on that file all the time. I don't even know if it would work out well with the loop inside the cron script...

---

- 2nd/ Another way would be to have a routine set directly on the database, but I don't have experience with the language. I don't know if it's worth learning to do that... This way the SQL script would run every 5 minutes, no need for cron. jobs.

---

- 3rd/ Last idea is I think the cheapest of the three but it's also quite risky I think. Instead of updating the databases every 5 minutes even when the user is not online, it would update it only when the user makes an action or connects. This would minimize drastically the amount of scripts running. However I found a little problem with that, if one user is to interact with another and that he disconnects the second user will not have the information since the first hasn't updated. Therefore if the second user wants the information it will have to update every user that is currently in interaction with him. I saw that topic discussed on another topic recently. I think it's the solution but it's also quite a challenge...

What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: Regarding #2, since you tagged this with [mysql], check out [MySQL event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html).

Comment: there are so many ways to do that for example u can use free Services to do that like [https://www.setcronjob.com/](https://www.setcronjob.com/) or u can calculate on user Action like u said. do a last Action on the user ( timestamp ) and write from there on a LOG what happend. for example ... user A has 1000 Ressources -> gets +200 ress per hour -> gets attacked after 3 hours -> then 5 hours nothing . the next Action regarding to the User A is calculated from theLOG and then u flag the LOG as DONE.

Comment: If player A connects or after he does n actions, every ressources from his city will update. Not only that, I found it will also have to update every players who have a "current relation" with A. For exemple player B who is sending a trader/or trading with A and player C who is sending troops to attack A. Even if B and C aren't connected, they will update automatically if A updates. That will become a mess if everyone has an action in progress with another one. It will update everyone one way or another. This is very complicated... Also SetcronJob.com isn't free.

Comment: my characters where limited :D @Ivan . sorry for setcronjobs but i have an old account there that was free and will be till 2017. then ist 10$ a year. and yes u are right. its a mess with the connected Players.

Comment: I found this https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/18b0ro/how_do_timebased_actions_in_browserbased_games/ but it's still hard to solve...

Comment: As nice as options 1 and 2 sound, they're not viable options as the number of users increases.  Option 3 isn't nearly as bad as it sounds as long as something or someone (usually a server) is regarded as the source of truth.  When it comes to whatever resource you're updating, they'll need to consult it instead of each other.  This has the added benefit that it makes cheating more difficult.